# Python : How to avoid using recursive calling?

Tags: python, recursion, return

I was being told that recursive calling should be avoided and so I tried to use the **return** to end the function and call back the main function. However, it does not work perfectly as I thought (the print statement in the main function is not being executed), may I know which part of the code is causing the issue or is there any other approach to deal with recursive callings?

```
def view():
     print("View page")
     while True:
          view_option = input("Please enter 'back': ")
          if view_option == '':
               continue
          elif view_option == "back":
               return
               # being told to not use main() 

def main():
     print("Main page")
     while True:
          main_option = input("Please enter 'view': ")
          if main_option == "view":
               view()
          else:
               continue

main()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Main page
Please enter 'view': view
View page
Please enter 'back': back
Please enter 'view':
```

**EXPECTING OUTPUT:**

```
Main page
Please enter 'view': view
View page
Please enter 'back': back
Main page
Please enter 'view':
```

Comment: If you want to print "Main page" repeatedly then the print statement should be inside your loop.

Comment: Some of this code doesn't make sense.  For instance, in `main`, the `else: continue` serves no purpose, right?  What would happen if you deleted it?  Nothing would change.  It would continue the loop anyway.  And in `view`, both `break` and `return` have the same effect inside the loop, right?  So the `elif` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the print statement inside of the while loop, like this:

```
def main():
    while True:
        print("Main page")
```